# Windows Store App Sqlite Vacuum

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, system.data.sqlite

I am using Sqlite For Windows Runtime.
I am doing few deletes, and then I try to fire a vacuum command so that I reduce the file size of the database.
The problem is that I get the following error:
SQL logic error or missing database

Here's the code:

```
        using (var con = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH)))
        {
            var command = con.CreateCommand("VACUUM;");
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a command have you tried Execute()?

```
using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbPath, true))
{
    db.Execute("VACUUM;");
}
```

That didn't throw for me.

Comment: Strange, I keep getting the same error.
I am using SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.8.3.1

Comment: And sqlite-net, though I cannot find the version.

Comment: Many thanks Tim, I just realized that I had modified earlier the SQlite.cs file provided by sqlite-net library. 
I got a clean copy of sqlite-net and now is working great.